# Add of javadoc file in UIAutomatorTesting

Tags: android, javadoc, android-uiautomator

can anyone plz tell me how from where i can find javadoc.jar for UIAutomator testing file so that i can add that to uiautomator.jar.I have searched on the net but i am unable to search javadoc.jar file?plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc does not seem to be easily available. Someone enterprising has asked the Android folk how to build the relevant code to generate the javadocs:

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-building/TOUKcGT2_vI "Like to build uiautomator.jar as source or javadoc jar"